# C# Displaying different entity properties in custom control

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

For the sake of this example, I have the following entities:

```
public class CustomerType
{
    public ItemType ItemType = ItemType.CustomerType;
    public int Id;
    public string Description;
}

public class Title
{
    public ItemType ItemType = ItemType.Title;
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}

public class PaymentMethod
{
    public ItemType ItemType = ItemType.PaymentMethod;
    public int Id;
    public string Method;
}

public class Customer
{
    public ItemType ItemType = ItemType.Customer;
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public CustomerType CustomerType;
    public Title Title;
    public PaymentMethod PaymentMethod;
}
```

I'm using EF6 and lazy loading is enabled, so when I retrieve a customer, the navigation properties are also filled. Now, in the winforms client, in the customer form, I have a custom control that should display the description of the 3 navigation properties.

The problem here is that each entity can have a different property which is used as its description (eg. CustomerType.Description, Title.Name, PaymentMethod.Method).

Is there a way to bind the custom control to that specific object? Is there a better way than to implement a switch() statement for each and every entity type, eg:

```
switch(typeof(objEntity))
{
    case "CustomerType": textBoxDescription.Text = objEntity.Description;
    case "Title": textBoxDescription.Text = objEntity.Name;
    //etc...
}
```

Maybe using reflection or some kind of interface?

Comment: This is usually solved by binding to a view model.

Comment: One common view model or a view model for every entity?

Comment: No, a model per view: *view* model.

Comment: But I have only 1 usercontrol and this should display any model.

Comment: You can have 100 views containing the same user control. View != user control.